# Equivalent inductance across two terminals

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor

[image]

What is role of the short circuit here? Can it be solved assuming a current/voltage source?

Comment: Which short circuit you mean? You just have a bunch of inductors and a bunch of wires connecting them in a seemingly random fashion. You might want to redraw the circuit to see it better.

Comment: By simple visual inspection  it's clearly 7 henries.

Comment: Adyy I think you need to accept an answer to this question if you are done with it. You don't have to accept my answer of course. If both answers have missed-the-point, then leave a comment explaining what you need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Equivalent inductance across two terminals*

Taking account of the short across the 10 henry inductor, just redraw the circuit and solve: -

[image]

It's just simple numbers now.

Comment: perhaps the OP wants to know the purpose of the short across the 10H

Comment: @RohitGupta the op's title is *Equivalent inductance across two terminals* and, the only two terminals I see are a and b

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the inductor that is shorted as there will be no current flowing through it.